# How to set an initial value of slider?

Tags: dynamic, slider

So I have

```
Slider[Dynamic@x, {0,3}]

Dynamic@Plot[1-Cos[2*x*t],{t,0,Pi}]
```

And I'd like x presents on the slider at x=1 value in the beginning and from that point I could change in both directions on the slider. How could I set the initial value?

Comment: Where is `x` supposed to be used? Should the value persist when notebook is saved or set to `1` again when you reopen the notebook. Please shed some light.

Comment: I want to use x inside Cosine function. I dont want notebook to save its value as 1. So I want to change it but when I plot the cos then in the first case I'd like to see 1-Cos(2*(x=1)*t) in the plot

Comment: Why not bind them together in a `DynamicModule[]`? `DynamicModule[{x = 1}, Column[{Slider[Dynamic @ x, {0, 3}], Dynamic @ Plot[1 - Cos[2 x t], {t, 0, π}]}]]`

Comment: okey, true. Thank you